# Azure B2C sign all users out

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need a method where I can destroy all user sessions after a product release forcing them to login.
It can be a manual step on portal, I just need to be able to do it.
I can't find anything in the documentation, and the quite generic potential search terms only appear to provide solutions and approaches to different issues.

Is this possible and if so, can you point me in the direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed this with Azure support engineer. Azure B2C doesn't support such feature that sign all users out.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, Thank you for your response. A real shame, means I need to rethink our session timeout strategy considering the session timeout for Azure B2C is completely broken .